# How do I verify this integral inequality?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to verify whether the following statement is true.

Let I = $[a,b]$ a closed interval in $R^1$

Assume $a(x)$ and $f(x)$ are integrable on $I$.

Assume also that $|a(x)| \leq c$ for every $x \in I$.

Then, $|\int^{b}_{a}a(x)f(x)dx| \leq c|\int^{b}_{a}f(x)dx|$

It "seems" true to me, but how do I actually show this?

Comment: Did you mean $|\int^{b}_{a}a(x)f(x)dx| \leq c\int^{b}_{a}|f(x)|dx$?

Comment: Somewhat confusing that $a$ is both the lower end of the interval $I$ *and* a function -- or is the confusion intentional?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Take $f$ so that $\int_a^b f(x)dx = 0$. For instance $f(x) = \sin(x)$ over $[0,2\pi]$. Now consider $a(x) = \sin(x)$ so that $|a(x)|\leq 1$.
But $|\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(x)dx| > 0= 1 |\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)dx|$.